# Unresolved reference: HtmlConverter in iText library

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, converters

I am trying to convert HTML String to PDF file in Android. I am using iText library but it is showing error:

`Unresolved reference: HtmlConverter`

Code:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlString, FileOutputStream(File(context.cacheDir.path + "/SensorReport.pdf")))
```

iText library import in module level gradle:

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

Please help.

Comment: The `HtmlConverter` is not part of iTextG 5.5.10. Instead it is part of html2pdf, a separate add-on for iText 7.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [pdfHTML page](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML) on the official web site.

I quote:

> pdfHTML is an iText 7 add-on that allows you to easily convert HTML and CSS into PDF documents.

You are using iTextG 5.5.10. That is not iText 7. Furthermore, having iText 7 isn't sufficient. You also need the pdfHTML add-on.

This explains the unresolved reference: `HtmlConverter` isn't an iText 5 class, it's not even an iText 7 class. The `HtmlConverter` class can be found in the pdfHTML add-on, which is an add-on on top of iText 7.

We didn't invest in an Android port of iText 7 because:

- The poor sales of iTextG didn't justify the investment in an Android port. That's odd, because an Android app is a distributed app and if the app is proprietary / closed source a commercial license is mandatory.
- Developers are now used to use technology such as Xamarin to develop on one platform and to port their applications to another platform.

If you want to keep on using iTextG 5, you need to use the XML Worker add-on. Note that iTextG and XML Worker are also AGPL (hence a commercial license will be needed if you don't want to distribute your source code and your application for free). Also: support for iTextG 5 and XML Worker is being discontinued. As you can read in the [intro of the HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml), XML Worker has many flaws.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please tell me what can I do now to convert HTML to pdf in Android? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I thought I already gave you that answer: either stick with iTextG 5, but use XML Worker; or upgrade to iText 7 + pdfHTML, but use either Java or C#, and compile it to an Android APK. That should be sufficient info to get started.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019 to use itext and pdfHTML you need add this dependency in build.gradle, I not find the answer in other sites, so i update this answer for next users.

implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.5'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:html2pdf:2.1.2'